# How to debug VB.NET windows service without Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, service

I have the source code of an windows service which is written in VB.NET

I came through various methods to debug this service using development environment (Visual Studio). But the challenge is, I need to deploy it in one of our servers as other application on that server need to access it. The server doesn't contain any development or debug tools. I am not allowed to install visual studio in it.

Is there any other way to debug the windows service on this server?

My intention is to understand the method call hierarchy, as this is a very complex code and I didn't write it. It has a very complex architecture and it is not possible to track the data flow only by looking at it.

Comment: Logging. Lots and lots of it?

Comment: In short, no. You would employ error protection in your code or Try/Catches where you can't. Then log the errors to see what it is having problems with.

Comment: The type of information I need, it will need me to write as much LOC for logging as my original code. I was looking for any command line or portable utility that does the job.

Answer (score 3):

If the only restriction is you can't install Visual Studio, I'd suggest you get the [Remote Tools for VS 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38184), which don't even need to be installed to the server, just a machine with a share accessible from the server.  Then follow the [instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I need to install the Remote Tools in my server itself, right? @Eric Walker

Comment: From my understanding, it's not necessary to install them on the server.  In the instructions link, look for "Running the remote debugging components from a share" for the instructions.  I believe the only restriction is you'll have to start the service manually and then attach the debugger once you've started the remote debugger on the server.